# How to add a clock widget to a screen?

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to make a GUI and I want a clock like this:
https://github.com/dwalker0044/KivyDigitalClock

I want to add it to a menu page that has buttons to navigate to other pages but I can't figure it out. I imported the file but I can't figure out how to add it to the screen. I've been having trouble with this for a while so if someone could help me out.

Here is my code:

main.py

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemanddock')

#KivyTest.py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
#from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
from glob import glob
from random import randint
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage

from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import sys
import platform

import webbrowser
import random
import os

import time
import datetime

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import *
from digitalclock import DigitalClock
from digitalclock import SecondsIndicator

class Face(Screen):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):
    def open_Browser(self):
        sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
        cef.Initialize()
        cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.google.com/",
                          window_title="Google")
        cef.MessageLoop()
        cef.Shutdown()
    def open_YouTube(self):
        sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
        cef.Initialize()
        cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.youtube.com/",
                            window_title="YouTube")
        cef.MessageLoop()
        cef.Shutdown()
    def open_Pictures(self):
        picturesApp = PicturesApp()
        picturesApp.run()
    def open_Camera(self):
        TestCamera().run()

class Commands(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    face = ObjectProperty(None)
    menu = ObjectProperty(None)


class IonApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition())
        m.add_widget(DigitalClock(name='Clock'))
        return m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    IonApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `add_widget()` method of a `ScreenManager` only accepts `Screen` instances.

You should be getting an error when you try to add a `DigitalClock` instance to your `ScreenManager`.

You need to add the `DigitalClock` instance to one of your `Screen` objects (like your `Menu` or your `Commands`) and then add that `Screen` to your `ScreenManager` using `add_widget()`.

The `KivyDigitalClock` code is not well prepared for inclusion into others code. Assuming that you have placed the digital clock code in a `digitalclock` folder (as it appears from your code), then you will also need a `Builder.load_file('digitalclock/digitalclock.kv')` call in your code. A good place for this would be just before your `IonApp().run()` call.

So here is what I think would work:

```
class IonApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = ScreenManager(transition = NoTransition())
        screen = Commands(name='commands')
        dc = DigitalClock()
        screen.add_widget(dc)
        m.add_widget(screen)
        dc.update()
        return m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_file('digitalclock/digitalclock.kv')
    IonApp().run()
```

Comment: How would I add the DigitalClock instance to a Screen object?

Comment: I have added a bit more detail to my answer above.

Comment: Appreciate the time and help. So I added it the way you set it up and there are no errors but it doesn't seem to show up. Do you think there is a way to add it to the kv file that I have?

Comment: Didn't know you had a kv file. That will probably change everything. Yes, you can add the `DigitalClock` to your kv file, as you would any other widget. But the `DigitalClock` code is not well written, and you will not be able to position it or size it. The code has hard-wired positions and sizes in it and ignores any settings you might use for `pos`, `pos_hint`, `size`, or `size_hint`.

Comment: Inspired by your attempts to use that DigitalClock, I did a fork of that project and made what I think is a better packaged DigitalClock. It is now a single file and you can use it just like any other widget. The project is [here](https://github.com/DaytonaJohn/KivyDigitalClock)

Comment: I got it working! Turns out I was redeclaring the pages in the kv file. Thanks so much for the help, John!